# Issue in Animating a View from one position to another position

Tags: android

Issue in animating a View from one position to another another. View is going to the given position but it's really fast even i added 5 sec delay also

```
 Path path = new Path();
 path.moveTo(625, 300);
 ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(device, View.X, View.Y, path);
animator.setDuration(5000);
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a problem in your code:

> `path.moveTo(625, 300);`

Path.moveTo() makes something like move pencil to 625, 300. And nothing more. You didn't tell to draw a path anywhere.

Changing moveTo to `path.lineTo(625,300)` should work for you.

You can see more examples of animation on Android Dev 
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

Comment: Thank you now it works.. but now view is startinting from the 0,0 position

Comment: @bin_ja, try adding `path.moveTo(<X position of your view>, <Y position of your view>)` before `lineTo`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how to get the X position of view and Y position of view

Comment: `<your view>.getX()` should be enough

Comment: I tried by int[] fromLoc = new int[2];
        `device.getLocationOnScreen(fromLoc);
        float startX = fromLoc[0];
        float startY = fromLoc[1];` but its getting wrong position

Comment: @bin_ja probably you need position in parent ViewGroup, not on screen